# stop bash script if react build fails

Tags: reactjs, bash, npm, build

I have a couple of deployments that has broken production, since the bash script continues if the build fails. How can I make sure that the script exits should the `npm run build` fail?

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source .env
ENVIRONMENT="$REACT_APP_STAGE"
if [ "$ENVIRONMENT" != "production" ]; then
    echo "improper .env NODE_ENV"
    exit
fi
git pull origin master
npm i
npm run build
rm -r /var/www/domain_name.dk/html/*
mv /var/www/domain_name.dk/website/build/* /var/www/domain_name.dk/html/
```

Comment: Doesn't `npm` set a non-zero exit code on failure? In this case, you can do a `npm run build || exit $?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is surprisingly easy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source .env
ENVIRONMENT="$REACT_APP_STAGE"
if [ "$ENVIRONMENT" != "production" ]; then
    echo "improper .env NODE_ENV" >&2  # Errors belong on stderr
    exit 1
fi
git pull origin master
npm i
npm run build || exit  # Exit if npm run build fails
...
```

By using the short-circuiting `||` operator, if `npn run build` fails, then the command on the right side excutes.  `exit` returns the exit status of the last executed command, so the script will exit with the same failure code that `npn run build` exited with.  If `npm run build` succeeds, then the `exit` is not executed.

Answer (score 3):

The `$?` operator gets the return code of the previously run command.  So, you can use it in conjunction with an `if` statement to verify that `npm run build` completed successfully.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source .env
ENVIRONMENT="$REACT_APP_STAGE"
if [ "$ENVIRONMENT" != "production" ]; then
    echo "improper .env NODE_ENV"
    exit
fi
git pull origin master
npm i
npm run build
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "npm run build successful"
else
  echo "npm run build failed" >&2
  exit 1
fi
rm -r /var/www/domain_name.dk/html/*
mv /var/www/domain_name.dk/website/build/* /var/www/domain_name.dk/html/
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I still have a lot to learn about bash scripting

Comment: `$?` is not an operator, it is a "special parameter".